# How to change spinner's dialog style ?

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

How to change spinner's dialog style ? I need to change background color from white.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Did you read the Android docs?  If you go to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html and do a CTRL+F search for color you should find what you are looking for

Comment: I can't find a way to change the dialog. It only offers to change color of "dropdown" style.